# i am using ConversationalRetrievalChain with custom prompt but it s not keeping chat history

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, langchain

i am using Langchain ConversationalRetrievalChain i want to add prompt and chatbot should remember chat history.but in my code bot is giving answers but not able to remember chat history.

````
def get_conversation_chain(self, vetorestore, prompt):
        con = """
        ----
        {context}
        ----
        here is the previous conversation
        ----
        {chat_history}
        ----
        """
        general_system_template = prompt + con

        general_user_template = "Question:```{question}```"
        Chat_system_template = (
            "Try to remember chat history Chat_history:{chat_history}"
        )
        messages = [
            SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(general_system_template),
            HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(general_user_template),
            ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(Chat_system_template),
        ]
        qa_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages)
        llm = ChatOpenAI(
            model_name="gpt-4-1106-preview",
            temperature=0,
        )

        memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
            memory_key="chat_history",
            return_messages=True,
        )

        conversation = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
            llm=llm,
            retriever=vetorestore.as_retriever(),
            memory=memory,
            chain_type="stuff",
            # get_chat_history=lambda h: h,
            combine_docs_chain_kwargs={
                "prompt": qa_prompt,
            },
        )
        return conversation
````